# Problem to Publish with SiteEdit (Tridion R5)

Tags: siteedit

I have a problem to publish page with SiteEdit. When I try to publish through SiteEdit the following error occurs:

[image: Error SiteEdit]

And not load the Targets Types to publish.
Does anyone know what could be happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I see in your screenshot you have a 403 error (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403).  This is a security access error.  It could be due to IIS security settings on the SiteEdit Proxy.  It may also be security settings on your actual website.

It's hard to tell just from the info you've provided, but take a look at the Event Viewer log in the CM, also IIS logs on the SE proxy (and any logs the SE Proxy may output [make sure to enable them]).  If there is no clear answer on what the issue is from the logs, post them here and we'll take a closer look/update my answer.